# Create folder/directory in Photo Album

Tags: iphone, photo-gallery

I want to create a folder in the Photo album and want to save images in that created photo album.

Is it possible? 
Is there any way to do this?

I have searched that and most of people saying that It is not possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If people say it not possible then why don't you accept the fact that it isen't possible?

Comment: Well, I am confirming here.As all those post were old dated. So IF is possible with ios 5.

Comment: Have you read the developer documentation on Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to create and save image to a new assets group using the [AssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=AssetsLibrary).

This library provide a method for creating new assets groups: [addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:resultBlock:failureBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722)

Comment: Thanks. We can create it only with ios 5 or above.

Comment: Yes, that true, but about 80% of the active iOS device seem to be running iOS 5. With iOS 6 coming soon this wil only increase. Thus this will not be a problem.